# Is there any way to read and write .doc files in the browser with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, laravel

I'm trying to build a web application to upload a doc file and read its content , then edit and save it to the database.
Is there any way i can read and edit a doc file using javascript or laravel ?

Answer (score 0):

Never heard of them but here is it:

[word-extractor](https://github.com/morungos/node-word-extractor)

from their github:

> Read data from a Word document using node.js